# Trouble installing Android SDK for Appcelerator studio on windows 7

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I have trouble installing Appcelerator studio on windows 7. I am getting the following error when trying to create a new mobile project (Alloy project) and run the same on an android device. Works fine on mobile web.

> [ERROR] :  No valid Android SDK targets found.
>
> [ERROR] :  Please download an Android SDK target API level 23 or newer
>   from the Android SDK Manager and try again.

The android SDK is already in place and have properly referenced it. Still no luck there.

Please find the platform specifics

Appcelerator Studio version : 4.5

Titanium SDK : 5.2.0GA

OS : Windows 7 (64 bit)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It requires level 23 or newer. Do you have it?

Comment: Yes, I do have API level 23 on my machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To identify the problem:
1. Verify android SDK path **$appc ti info -t android**

```
Android SDK
  Android Executable          = /Users/kk/Library/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android
  ADB Executable              = /Users/kk/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb
  SDK Path                    = /Users/kk/Library/android-sdk-macosx
```

Is this what you wanted to refer ?

2. Verify API Level 23(Android SDK 6.0) is installed or not from the above command output.

`android-23
        Name                      = Android 6.0
        API Level                 = 23
        Revision                  = 1
        Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearRound360x360, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRound480x480, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidWearRoundChin360x325, AndroidWearRoundChin360x330, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearSquare320x320
        ABIs                      = armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64
        Path                      = /Users/kk/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-23`

3. Verify Android SDK path in the studio, is it referring to the same path ?

That you can check from, Appcelerator Studio ->Preferences->Platforms ->Android

Check "Android SDK Home" path.

And also see installed android SDK's from, by clicking on "Install SDKs...", this will open up the dialog. Is "Android 6.0" selected here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to select or install Android SDK's via Appcelerator Studio -> Preferences -> Platforms -> Android -> Install SDKs, the versions are greyed out, see below:

[image: Options greyed out]

I updated my Android SDKs using `C:\android-sdk-win\tools\android.bat` but this is not enough. I opened my Tiapp.xml file and clicked `install` below "Deployment targets":

[image]

I noticed that API level 23 (Android SDK 6.0) was not checked, so I selected it and clicked configure to install the SDK (or update it):

[image]

This solved the problem for me!