# A valid android SDK could not be found...an existing SDK with platform-tools and at least one platform needs to be registered with the IDE

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
A valid android SDK could not be found...an existing SDK with platform-tools and at least one platform needs to be registered with the IDE...
```

i have done a lot of thing just like install 2 to 3 times visual studio 2015,download 2 to 3 times Xamarin but still getting the same error..HOW TO SOLVE??
[image]

I AM USING 64 BIT WINDOWS 10 OS..
now this error comes..how to solve??
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one upgrade to Android SDK 25.1.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502299/how-does-one-upgrade-to-android-sdk-25-1-3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appcelerator on Windows: No valid Android SDK Targets Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398216/appcelerator-on-windows-no-valid-android-sdk-targets-found)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to **Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager...**

Inside of Android SDK Manager you need to update the following tools

- Android SDK Tools
- Android SDK Platform-tools

You also might want to install API 25, API 24 and API 23 SDK platforms. Also if you plan to use the Google Emulator install some relevant x86/x86_64 System images.

When you have done this, close the Android SDK Manager and restart Visual Studio and try building again.

**EDIT:**
In the comments you say that you are unable to open Android SDK manager. This sounds a lot like the installation of it went wrong.

Go to: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html at the bottom of the page download the command line tools and install them. Make sure to take note of the path you specify for the installation. You need to enter the same path in Visual Studio under: **Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings > Android SDK Location**

While you are at it. You might also want to install latest Java JDK 8 and change the path in Visual Studio same place as Android SDK Location to point at that newer JDK.

Comment: I am unable to open android sdk manager..it is not opening i dont know why it is happening...

Comment: the android sdk manager is invisible..i.e. we can't click on sdk manager option

Comment: ok...that means i need to download and  install the android studio..just give me some time..

Comment: No just the command line tools. You don't need Android Studio itself. It is at the bottom of the page I linked to.

Comment: yes i got it and download 145 mb .exe file..now what should i do??

Comment: I already installed but still getting the same error.Now what should i do??

Comment: And did you change the path in Visual Studio to the newly installed?

Comment: yes..it tells us some different error  the installed android sdk is too old...version 25.1.3 or newer is required

Comment: nothings comes in update...and same problem..where should i change?

Comment: sir this error comes:how to solve??Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 Demo Apps in visual studio

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main  :  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 Demo_apps

Comment: Update Java JDK

Comment: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 3, position 3.

Comment: Fix the errors in your layout. Make a new question with details if you want help.

Answer (score 14):

I resolved the problem by going to:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp
I found the following file in there: tools_r25.2.2-windows.zip (as of 13/10/2016)
I opened the zip file, there is a 'tools' folder.
I unzipped the tools folder to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk' and overwrite the existing tools folder.
Restart Visual Studio and all the layout file can be displayed normally.

Good luck everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Download and Install Android SDK. https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
then set its location in VS: Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android SDK location

Comment: sir this is the android studio..is it need to download android studio??

Comment: look at the very bottom of the page. "installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe" or "android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip"

Comment: where??describe me details

Comment: after download the second error comes what should i do???version 25.1.3.

Comment: click "Open Android SDK" link or open Android SDK manager any other way(from "tools-android-android SDK manager" for example). Then update or install: Android SDK tools, Android SDK Platform-tools, Android *some version*

Answer (score 1):

While the Xamarin is updating, that error can see.

Solved is found the tools zip file:

C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\temp\tools_r25.2.4-windows (or your active last tools, doesnt matter. for ex. tools_r23.0.1)

-> Open that zip and unzip in "tools" folder.

-> Cut that folder and, paste parent folder 
   (C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xokzC.png)go to Tools-->Android--> Android SDK MANAGER

[Remember select only those which is ticked in the image ... when you click these other items under the clicked item would automatically be selected .. you need to unselect those]

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue. Firstly I tried to Updated the Android SDK from SDK Manager by running "SDK Manager.exe" from my PC. But at that time nothing was working, after that I restarted my PC and launched Visual Studio as an Administrator. Then created a new Android project and everything was working fine.

Comment: I am in the same position.  I have spent all morning trying to fix it.  Deleted stuff, reinstalled things, changed paths.  Nothing.  If I start VS as administrator it works, otherwise it refuses.  Thanks for posting your "solution".  At least I can keep moving forward for now.