# Appcelerator Studio Android SDK Install Failed 2017

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I was installing Android SDK on

> Windows 7 from Appcelerator Studio -> Window -> Preferences -> Studio
>   -> Platforms -> Android -> Install SDKs... (button).

After hours of download of SDK and system images of Android, this error popped up

```
Error encountered during update

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Read timed out

java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
Stream Closed
Could not write file: C:\Windows\system32\tools\android.bat.
tools\android.bat (Access is denied)
Could not write file: C:\Windows\system32\platform-tools\adb.exe.
platform-tools\adb.exe (Access is denied)
Could not write file: C:\Windows\system32\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe.
build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe (Access is denied)
```

And now my hard disk is eaten up by these download over 15 GB and no clue where all downloads have gone. I wanted to delete all images and other sdk tools and stuff downloaded by Appcelerator Studio.

> I am running Windows 7

Please help.

[image: Android SDK not installed]

Answer (score 1):

first check if the question is asked already using Google or the search function of SO. You can probably solve this matter using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006274/trouble-installing-android-sdk-for-appcelerator-studio-on-windows-7/44848453#44848453)

Also make sure that Appcelerator has Administrator rights to be able to write files on your hard drive (looking at the errors I think this is the main issue).

The Android SDK is normally installed in this folder: `C:\android-sdk-win` (or something similar) 
The Android NDK is normally installed in this folder: `C:\android-ndk-win` (or something similar) 
And yes, Android will take several GBs of your hard drive.